# How can I change the size of a figure made in Java Graphics2D with a slider?

Tags: java, swing, polygon, graphics2d, jslider

I'm trying to make a program with java using Graphics 2D that paints polygons between 3 and 8 sides and that I can resized with a slider but I do not know how to do for change it size with the slider evenly.

Here is a example of my pentagon drawn

```
if (sides == 5){
        g.drawLine(110+x,135-y, 10+x,205-y);
        g.drawLine(10+x,205-y, 48+x, 320-y);
        g.drawLine(48+x,320-y, 170+x,320-y);
        g.drawLine(170+x,320-y, 205+x,205-y);
        g.drawLine(205+x,205-y, 110+x,135-y);
    }
```

Now I want to change its size evenly.
(I can move my polygon in X and Y axis).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`AffineTransformation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html)

Answer (score 2):

## You could...

Use a [`AffineTransformation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) to scale the `Graphics` context

[image: Scale]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane tp = new TestPane();

                JSlider slider = new JSlider(10, 200);
                slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        tp.setScale(slider.getValue());
                    }
                });
                slider.setValue(100);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tp);
                frame.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int scale = 100;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(250, 350);
        }

        public void setScale(int value) {
            if (value != scale) {
                int old = scale;
                this.scale = value;
                firePropertyChange("scale", old, scale);
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public int getScale() {
            return scale;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            double scaleValue = getScale() / 100d;
            System.out.println(scaleValue);
            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scaleValue, scaleValue);
            g2d.setTransform(at);

            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;

            g2d.drawLine(110 + x, 135 - y, 10 + x, 205 - y);
            g2d.drawLine(10 + x, 205 - y, 48 + x, 320 - y);
            g2d.drawLine(48 + x, 320 - y, 170 + x, 320 - y);
            g2d.drawLine(170 + x, 320 - y, 205 + x, 205 - y);
            g2d.drawLine(205 + x, 205 - y, 110 + x, 135 - y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

This is going to scale both the size and position though, which may not be desirable...

## You could...

Use the 2D Graphics shape API instead.  This will allow you to define a shape, independently and simply paint it as you need.  The benefit of this is you can control the transformation better, transforming the scale without transforming the position

[image: Scaled Shape]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane tp = new TestPane();

                JSlider slider = new JSlider(10, 200);
                slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        tp.setScale(slider.getValue());
                    }
                });
                slider.setValue(100);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tp);
                frame.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int scale = 100;
        private PentegonShape pentegonShape;

        public TestPane() {
            pentegonShape = new PentegonShape(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(250, 350);
        }

        public void setScale(int value) {
            if (value != scale) {
                int old = scale;
                this.scale = value;
                firePropertyChange("scale", old, scale);
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public int getScale() {
            return scale;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;

            double scaleValue = getScale() / 100d;
            Shape shape = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scaleValue, scaleValue).createTransformedShape(pentegonShape);
            g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y));
            g2d.draw(shape);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class PentegonShape extends Path2D.Double {

        public PentegonShape(double width, double height) {
            moveTo(width / 2, 0);
            lineTo(width, height / 3d);
            lineTo((width / 5d) * 4, height);
            lineTo((width / 5d), height);
            lineTo(0, height / 3d);
            closePath();
        }

    }

}
```

Have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Working with Geometry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) in particular

Comment: It works great. But it is too complicated to my actually knowledge. I do not understand so good. Thank you!

Comment: @Arbelaju I don't understand the maths, I just know it works :P

Comment: Is there any way to make it only through Graphics2d, Graphics and AffineTransform? Or maybe using an scalar in each point?

Comment: First example...Understand though, you are transforming the `Graphics` context itself, this means you will scale ALL the properties of the `Graphics`  context (size, position, rotation what ever)

Comment: Do you speak spanish?