# Change size of shapes in Java when clicking an events

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the size of shapes every time user clicks on the radio button. However Im having problem with the small and medium it's doing well but for the large I dont know the right way of doing this. Cans someone help me on this.

```
 protected int radius = 1;
   public void circle(Graphics shapes)
{
    shapes.setColor(color);
    shapes.fillOval(250,100, 100/radius, 100/radius);
}

public void rectangle(Graphics shapes)
{
    shapes.setColor(color);
    shapes.fillRect(250,100,100/radius,100/radius);
}
public void square(Graphics shapes)
{
    shapes.setColor(color);
    shapes.fillRect(200,100,200/radius,100/radius);
}
public void triangle(Graphics shapes)
{     
    int[] x = new int[3];
    int[] y = new int[3];
    x[0]=300; x[1]=350; x[2]=250;       
    y[0]=100/radius; y[1]=200; y[2]=200;    
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon(x,y,3);
    shapes.setColor(color);
    shapes.fillPolygon(polygon);
}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {    
    if(click.getSource() == small){
        radius = 1*2;repaint();
    }else if(click.getSource() == medium){
        radius = 1; repaint();
    }
    else if(click.getSource() == large){
        radius = 1; repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change the size of the shapes (reinitialise them); use the Shape's API which allows you to create new shapes from other instances use a AffineTranform; or change the Graphics context scale when they are painted, someone like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067700/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-a-figure-made-in-java-graphics2d-with-a-slider/29067753#29067753) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041397/how-to-paint-a-group-of-quadcurves-using-java-graphics2d/30042600#30042600) for example

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the links. But it seems your not helping those who are not yet familiar with java.

Comment: How so? I outlined the basic concepts you could use to solve you're problem and provided at least three examples demonstrating those principles. Should I make you read an appropriate tutorial like [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) first instead? But if you're not familiar with Java, then I'd question the fact that you're trying to work the complex/advance topics of GUI and graphics development

Comment: You're also going to want to have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) as, based on your out-of-context code snippt, it seems you may not have an understanding of how painting works in Swing

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Not that you should expect more than the extensive help already offered by @MadProgrammer though..